# Printing text from google search using python and selenium does not work?

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I have a question about python and selenium I am trying to get the text from a link and print it but it will not print out the text my code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Safari()

driver.implicitly_wait(6) 

driver.get("http://www.google.ca")

name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="lst-ib"]""")

name.send_keys('how old is Obama')

name.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

name2=driver.find_element_by_class_name("_uX kno-fb-ctx").text

print(name2)
```

Comment: Formatting: select code and press Ctrl-K... voila... its formatted correctly. If you have more info about where what goes wrong/error code... than that's more than welcome to post by editing your question and modify. It shows effort.

Comment: I've never tried but sending a request with a query param such as "q=how+old+is+Obama", waiting a bit, clicking the button, waiting a bit longer, then searching the DOM is probably how I'd approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems two-fold to me. There is one problem of selenium not being able to find the element and then there's the problem of Safari not being able to search even the most basic elements.

For the first problem, I suggest you use the lower level elements of the '_uX kno-fb-ctx' element such as the '_XWk' element or '_Tfc _j0k'. They work succesfully.

As for the problem with Safari, you can use Chrome or Firefox. You might have to download the geckodriver for Firefox.

And I suggest you use Beautiful Soup if all you want it to do is scrape text from websites. It's faster and is less prone to such technical bugs and is much more precise.

Comment: There is no answer in this. This should be a comment and not the answer itself.

Comment: Actually this solved my problem I used Chrome and my code ran perfectly so I would definitely say this is the answer